# AutoFill method in Range class error

Tags: vba, excel, range, autofill

I'm trying to make an autofill function in VBA and can't make it work. I get the error message: AutoFill method in Range class error. Can someone please explain to me why I cant make it work, or better yet a VBA code that makes it work. Thanks in advance, see code below: (The code is just a part of a bigger code and I'm pretty sure it's nothing wrong with SourceRange or FillRange, I get the error on row: `SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=FillRange`)

```
Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0))
Set FillRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Selection, ActiveCell.Offset((Lenght1.Count), 0))
SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=FillRange
```

Comment: Try `msgbox`ing your `SourceRange` and `FillRange` right after you have them set. Are you getting the expected values?

Comment: @Marcus Forsberg test my answer below, as long as `Lenght1.Count` gets a number in your code it shpuld work

Comment: @Marcus Forsberg  have you tried my code below, did it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation, it is better to avoid `ActiveCell` and `Selection` ;  try instead to use `Range("B1")`  (for example) , or `Cells(1,"B")`.

```
Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address & "," & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address)
Set FillRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Selection.Address & "," & ActiveCell.Offset((Lenght1.Count), 0).Address)

SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=FillRange
```

**Edit 1**:

```
Set SourceRange1 = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A1:A2")

' you need to set the Range from A1
Set FillRange1 = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A1:A10")

SourceRange1.AutoFill Destination:=FillRange1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I tried to make a simple Autofill as below and still get the same error. Makes me thing there is some sort of addition that unaviable?

Set SourceRange1 = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A1:A2")
Set FillRange1 = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A4:A10")

SourceRange1.AutoFill Destination:=FillRange1

Comment: @MarcusForsberg see my edited answer , you need to set `FillRange1` to Range("A1:A10")